# Alternatives for Data analytics on Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, amazon-redshift, spark-cassandra-connector, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We need to perform analytics and reporting on our Cassandra database .

Following is the approaches we have identified till now .

1)Use spark on top of cassandra .

Drawbacks :

- We will be heavily using aggregations functions and in cassandra as
  the data is partitioned by row key . If the groupby rows dosent match
  with our row key then performance would be bad .
- No out of the box UI for spark for showing  reports
- It needs a programmer(java/scala/python) to add/modify the future
  requirements which leads to high maintenance cost

2)Move the data to red shift and perform analytics on top of it .

- This works out well for our aggregations queries as redshift is
  columnar database.
- Ability to specify sort and distribute based on our analytics queries
  while table creation in redshift
- UI partners available for reporting
- SQL supported for adhoc queries (less maintenance)

Draw backs :

- We would need to move data from cassandra to redshift .We have
  identified AWS Firehose to do this for us .Along with writing to
  cassandra we would also write to firehose stream which would write to
  redshift for us .
- AWS cost involved in redshift and Firehose .

So far we are leaning towards redshift .
Are there any mistakes in my assumptions above.?
Are there any alternatives present ?

Answer (score 1):

Spark with Cassandra is probably the more common choice.  Two points worth noting, a) you can cache RDDs in memory with Spark and 2) Spark SQL works fine, you don't need to use a programming language with Spark.